# java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'smallPDF_463KB.pdf' does not exist

Tags: java

Q: what is the simplest java code line to figure out where my java program is trying to search for a file?

Assumption: "smallPDF_463KB.pdf" is in the classpath. (This assumption could be true or false.)

I am receiving the above exception as clearly it states the My java main program is NOT able to find the given file smallPDF_463KB.pdf.
This exception is happening even though I believe that "smallPDF_463KB.pdf" is in the classpath.

What are the Java code line/lines (eg "user.dir" or any other java property) that I can insert into my main program and then I can figure-out as-to-where my Java main program is trying to search this file.
So, that I can assert what is going wrong accurately.

Exception details:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'smallPDF_463KB.pdf' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1135)
    at main.CmisClient.createDocument(CmisClient.java:91)
    at main.CmisClient.main(CmisClient.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.CmisClient.createDocument(CmisClient.java:95)
    at main.CmisClient.main(CmisClient.java:35)
```

Comment: Can you show the code your passing the path to whatever file input object

Comment: Java does not search the classpath for a file; it looks in the current directory.

Comment: Which current directory? the directory from where the Main program is running or the directory of the package of the class file from where the File path is invoked?

Comment: @peeskillet I could have paste the code here but SO is not allowing me to do so as it says code is too long for this comment block.

Comment: Below answer from @peeskillet have solved my exception.
Now my program is able to find that file, as I have moved it to 'Project Root'. thanks for your attempt.
"peeskillet" had the prior knowledge and was able to direct me to move the file at 'Project Root'.
My intention here is to discover the process to acquire that knowledge that "peeskillet" had prior hand.
So, still I am looking for a generic solution if anybody wants to brain storm and get me those lines of java code that can print the path of the 'Project Root' is where the main program trying to search for the file.

Comment: @SanjayTank If an answer solves this question, you should accept it (the check mark). If you have another question, then you should post another question. This a Q & A site, and not really a help desk.

Comment: @peeskillet I appreciate you attempting my question challenge. I give credit to you but I think the answer I was looking for has come to me from "user1631616" and I am opting his answer as generic solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file from your path and then print absolute path of that file:
i.e.

```
File file = new File("<your path>");
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as this tell us where the Java program is trying to find the file.
And I accept it and generic solution.
So, Java developer need NOT remember always to place the files at "Project Root" as "peeskillet" has pointed above.
Instead, place the code lines that @user1631616 has given us and figure out where actually at the run-time the java program is trying to search for the file and apply appropriate diagnosis.

Comment: How can you print the path if the file can't be found?

Answer (score 1):

new File(".").getAbsoluteFile(), will give you a string with the folder it is searching in.

Comment: This also a correct answer to my question, I have tested it and it prints the path where the Java Program is trying to search the file.
thanks you for attempting my question.

Comment: I had the same problem while scanning the file from webapp. it does not scan it from the workspace directory. it takes it from the Eclipse webapp

Answer (score 0):

erm, Mr. Tank.. the file path must be relative or absolute. It doesn't matter if its on the classpath or not.